# Laravel Jobs and Reserved Status or Reserved Queue

Tags: laravel-4, redis, queue, jobs, supervisord

I have a script run as a job when pushed in a queue. I have a couple of other queues and all of these are handled by the supervisord. I am using the Redis as a queue driver with Laravel 4.2.

I want to know about the different statuses of the jobs:

- The Job waiting to be executed
- The Failed Job
- The Reserved Job

The problem with these different statuses is that I have thousands of the jobs in the reserved queue `queue:xyz:reserved` (I don't know why) which are pushed in the queue `queue:xyz` and these jobs(from reserved queue) blocks the execution of the newly pushed jobs.

Following is the command run by the supervisord to process the jobs:
    `php artisan queue:work --queue=xyz --tries=1 --daemon --env=prodEnv`
    My question/s are:

- why a job is pushed in the reserved queue/state
- why is it pushed back to the original queue by the Laravel?
- What is the difference between the failed and reserved job? OR
- When is a job marked/considered as failed or reserved?

The process of pushing the reserved jobs to the original queue slows down the processing of the new jobs in the queue which I want to make it faster by handling these reserved jobs things.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to finally sort it out.

In my case, this was because of a run time error.

I had a job which had sections of code say A,B,C. Section C caused a run time error every time and while I could see the effects of sections A and B as expected, I noticed the job was pushed to reserved state and the effects of executing section C were not observed.

Interestingly enough, I had another Job running that fixed the run time error some time later and then section C was executed and the job was removed from reserved jobs.

This may not answer all of your questions directly but I hope it helps in finding them.